# How to write data to CSV file into correct column heading in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a dictionary data that I need to write it into a CSV file under the heading `Form Name Type & Definition`, the dictionary data to write is in the code snippet below.

**writeData.py**

```
def writeCSV():

    # Dictionary Data to write received from Form Submit
    csvData = {
                'form'                      : 'Customer', 
                'Customer [form]'           : 'Customer is module for recording information related to customer such as Name, Address, Date of Birth, Place of Birth, ID Number, etc.', 
                'Salutation [label]'        : 'A greeting in words or actions, or the words used at the beginning of a letter or speech. This field has values such as Mr, Ms, Miss.', 
                'First Name English [label]': 'The name that was given to you when you were born and that comes before your family name. This field accept only English Character.'
                }

    items = {key:value  for key,value in csvData.iteritems() if key != 'form'} 

    form = csvData.get('form')

    Columns = ['Form','Name','Type','Definition']

    string  = ''

    with open("myfile.csv","w+") as f:

        # Write Heading
        for col_header in Columns:
            string = string + "," + col_header
        f.write(string[1:]+'\n')

        # Write Data Body
        string = ''
        for key,value in items.iteritems():
            string = form + "," + key + "," + " " + ","+value
            f.write(string)
            f.write('\n')

    return ''

writeCSV()
```

However, after I executed the python script above, data was written correctly under the heading `Form`, `Name`, and `Type`. Yet, under the heading `Definition`, the data was expanded to some more column be young its heading `Definition`.

[image: CSV file after run script]

I searched around but no clue why it expands column like this, or the amount of data is limited inside on csv column? What's wrong with this, how can I write its data in correct column of CSV file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that csv delimiter each column by a special character. In your case, you are using a comma ','. But in your text also commas occur. So the csv takes this as a delimiter and interprets it as a new column. You can switch from comma to semicolon ';' as a delimiter. But even then you have to ensure that there are no semicolons in your original text.

If you make it this way you need to change these lines:

```
string = string + ";" + col_header  # ; instead of ,
string = form + ";" + key + ";" + " " + ";"+value
```

But I would suggest using a library, like @Nathaniel suggests

Comment: yes it is. I have tried to remove comma "," separated from my `csvData` dict, and it works. Would like to adding that the delimiter also determined by software application to view the file as I viewed it with Libre Office Cal, it allow us to choose text delimiter on opening file, by selecting a different delimiter from script, resulting in different result as well. Anyway, thanks very much for helpful answer :)

Comment: This is why there is a `csv` module in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You may have success converting your dictionary to a data frame and then saving it to a csv:

```
import pandas as pd

csvData = {'form'                      : 'Customer', 
           'Customer [form]'           : 'Customer is module for recording information related to customer such as Name, Address, Date of Birth, Place of Birth, ID Number, etc.', 
           'Salutation [label]'        : 'A greeting in words or actions, or the words used at the beginning of a letter or speech. This field has values such as Mr, Ms, Miss.', 
           'First Name English [label]': 'The name that was given to you when you were born and that comes before your family name. This field accept only English Character.'
           }

# Try either of these
df = pd.DataFrame(csvData, index=[0])
#df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(csvData)

# Output to csv
df.to_csv('myfile.csv')
```

Without some example data, it is difficult to test this on your data.

Comment: And if you want to stick to the standard library, there's the csv module https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @Nathaniel, that is a very interesting package I've never known before, I will try that, thanks very much :)

Comment: @HouyNarun No problem!

Answer (score 0):

It did not expand into adjacent columns; because of the size of the text, it doesn't fit the column width, and Excel's default is to draw that text over adjacent columns.  You can verify this is the case by selecting cells that it appears to have expanded into, and seeing they are in fact empty.  You can also change the way these cells are displayed, "wrapping" their contents within the column provided (making the rows taller).

Comment: Thanks and apologized  could be my uploaded image confused you specifically at column row D:4, look very much like it is one single sentence :)

Comment: `D4` actually *is* one single sentence; its row 3 that got split.